# Pasar datos obtenidos de un formulario a un componente hijo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

quiero poder pasar datos de un formulario a un componente hijo. Estoy usando react hooks form, ya me devuelve el DATA pero no se como poder pasarlo a  un componente y luego destructurar los datos para mostrarlos en una tabla.

```
export const Form = () => {
  
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  

  const onSubmit = ( data,e ) => {
    e.target.reset();
    console.log(data)
  };

  return (
    <form>
       <input
             type="text"
             aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
             placeholder="Ingrese un nombre"
             className="form-control"
            {...register("Nombre", { maxLength: 80 })}
       />
    </form>

    <section>
     <Table />
    </section>

)

}
```

Como pueden ver quiero pasar todo lo que me trae data a mi componente Table, como hago ?

Comment: cual es el proposito?, enviar data de un formulario a un componente?.. porque no poner el formulario dentro de <table>?

Comment: No podria ya que tengo el formulario separado del componente que tiene el table

Answer (score 0):

Creo que hay otras maneras de hacer esto, te recomiendo que utilizes elementos controlados por `react`. Pero si realmente lo necesitas hacer así, creo que lo mejor sería hacer un estado con el hook `useState` y al ahora de hacer el `submit` cambiar ese estado para que contenga dichos datos del formulario. Y por otro lado hacer un componente que reciba como prop el estado. Así cuando se actualice el estado se re-renderiza el componente con los datos del formulario.

```js
export const Form = () => {

  //Nuevo estado
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(null);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: {
      errors
    },
  } = useForm();



  const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    e.target.reset();
    //Actualizamos el estado
    setFormData(data);
    console.log(data);
  };

  return ( <
    form >
    <
    input type = "text"
    aria - describedby = "basic-addon1"
    placeholder = "Ingrese un nombre"
    className = "form-control" { ...register("Nombre", {
        maxLength: 80
      })
    }
    /> <
    /form>

    <
    section >
    <
    Table 
      //Lo pasamos como prop al hijo
      datosFormulario = {formData}
    / >
    <
    /section>

  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que en register tienes las props que faltan en el input. El value el onChange etc.

El onSubmit debería ir en el form no register.

Y yo también haría lo que hizo Fran Acuna. UseState y lo pasamos como prop.

En submit no olvides el e.preventDefault()